# How to make DataGridView move to next cell instead of next row after AutoComplete string selection made VB.net?

Tags: vba, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, autocomplete

I have a DataGridView where some of the cells only allow values from an AutoCompleteStringCollection. When I enter the cell and begin to type a value, a drop-down window appears with viable options. If I finish typing it out and hit enter or tab, I go to the next cell. However, if I start typing and then select an option from the drop-down menu, it moves one row down in the same column. I’d like it to move to the next cell/next column SAME row after selecting from the drop-down box. Any idea how I go about doing this. Thanks in advance for your help!!

```
Private Sub getData(ByVal DataCol As AutoCompleteStringCollection)
    Dim comm As SqlCommand
    Dim adapt As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT DISTINCT ValueOption From HR.dbo.RecruitVal WHERE ColumnName = 'Source'"

    Try

        If SqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Broken Then SqlConn.Close()
        If SqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then SqlConn.Open()

        comm = New SqlCommand(sql, SqlConn)
        adapt.SelectCommand = comm
        adapt.Fill(ds)
        adapt.Dispose()
        comm.Dispose()
        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            DataCol.Add(row(0).ToString())
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub RAppSrc(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles RAppGrid.EditingControlShowing
    Dim titleText As String = RAppGrid.Columns(RAppGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText
    If titleText.Equals("Source") Then
        Dim autoText As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)
        If autoText IsNot Nothing Then
            autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            Dim dataCol As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
            getData(dataCol)
            autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = dataCol
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Cell - Validating

```
    If (appCol.Name = "Source") Then
        Dim sql As String = " SELECT 1 FROM Hr.dbo.RecruitVal WHERE ColumnName = 'Source'AND ValueOption = @Source "
        Dim sql2 As String = "SELECT DISTINCT ValueOption from HR.dbo.RecruitVal WHERE ColumnName = 'Source' "
        Dim com As New SqlCommand(sql, SqlConn)
        Dim com2 As New SqlCommand(sql2, SqlConn)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim val As String
        Dim val2 As String
        com.Parameters.Add("@Source", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = e.FormattedValue
        val = com.ExecuteScalar()
        reader = com2.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()
                val2 += reader.GetValue(0) & "," & Space(3)
            End While
        End If
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue) Then
            'Do Nothing
        ElseIf val = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show(" Please Enter a valid Source Option" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Valid Options are as Follows:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf + val2.ToString(), "VALIDATION ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            RAppGrid.EndEdit()
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: I've just tested few scenarios and I was unsuccessfull. The function to move to the next cell was easy, but it all ends up on the fact that `EditingControlShowing` eats up the `Enter` key and won't pass it to i.e. further `KeyDown`, which I hooked up. It works with all keys but `Enter`, doh. Of course, one way is to use `TAB` key instead :-). But that's not an anwer to your question...

Comment: In my scenario, I make autocomplete by myself, by using event of textchange, keydown and keypress, I directly find just top 1 of record each time to I change my text in cell.

Comment: In another schenario, autoText declaration is put generally withevents, end then use previewkeyevent of autotext to run code of If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then,  DataGridView1.EndEdit(), do validation, and last time set pos of cell, example: DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Item(1, 0),  End If

Answer (score 0):

I've tested few scenarios and found out, that the `Enter` key wouldn't work (all but `Enter` works). I found [this answer on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20ac423e-8ad4-4281-a8ca-e37d5380d3df/datagridview-event-to-handle-enter-key?forum=winforms):

> For the enter key, ProcessDataGridViewKey will return true meaning that it has handled the key so you won't get a KeyDown event for it.
>
> If you override ProcessDataGridViewKey and handle the enter key making it return false, you will get the key events you are expecting.

```
{
 Keys key = (e.KeyCode & Keys::KeyCode); //removes control, alt modifiers
  if(key == Keys.Enter)
 {
   //Still do the default processing for enter so it will move down to the next row
   Base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
   return false; //say we have *not* handled the key
 }
 else
 {
   return Base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
 }
}
```

The above code is in C#, obvously.

The move function then may look like this (tested only VB.NET version bellow and only with other keys than `Enter`):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    If IsNothing(TryCast(e.Control, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)) = False Then
        Dim tb As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl = e.Control
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf DataGridView1_Keydown
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_Keydown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) ' Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DataGridView1
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        dgv.EndEdit()
        If IsNothing(dgv.CurrentCell) = False Then
            Dim cc As DataGridViewCell = dgv.CurrentCell
            If cc.ColumnIndex < dgv.Columns.Count - 2 Then ' if there's a cell to the right of the current one
                dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows(cc.RowIndex).Cells(cc.ColumnIndex + 1)
            ElseIf cc.RowIndex < dgv.Rows.Count - 1 Then   ' if there's a row bellow
                dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows(cc.RowIndex + 1).Cells(0)
            Else
                ' do nothing, stay where you are
            End If
            dgv.CurrentCell.Selected = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```